# What does python array -1 mean?

Tags: python

I found something like losss_test[-1] in python script.

I was looking for web pages to get some answers for [-1].

But, I can not get the proper answer. If someone know it, please tell me the meaning on it...

Comment: Negative numbers index from the end of the array. Most Python tutorials cover this.

Comment: Above one is nice summary, thank you for teaching it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative numbers for an index takes the values starting from the **end** of the array.